# How to register all containers (IUnityContainer type)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, containers, ioc-container

I am using IUnityContainer for dependency injection in Mvc project. In my unityconfig, I am resolving the services as below.

```
private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> Container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IService1, Service1>();
        container.RegisterType<IService2, Service2>();
        // and more ..
        return container;
    });
```

When I add a new service to my project, I must add a new line to that method. Is there any way to make it dynamic? I dont want to add a new line here when a new service created.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest some event handlers added in this method. And whenever you add service it should call the event and the event is fired here in this method.

Comment: why don't you use a different IOC Framework , a lot of them by default don't need every type to be registered if it ofollows default namng conventions of having the same name exactly except the interface with the added "I"

Comment: I would advice defining a few clearly defined abstractions, such as [ICommandHandler<TCommand>](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92). This allows you to batch-register all implementations of such abstraction in one line of code, and has many other very interesting benefits, such has keeping your code SOLID and making it really easy to add cross-cutting concerns such as logging, audit trailing, security checks, validation, and many other concerns.